# How to zoom camera to cover the path in android googlemap?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have covered multiple locations in `Google map` using `LatLng.Builder` and it's working.
Is there any way I could cover the whole path between two location in `Google map`?

My Curent Code to include multiple locations

```
builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(LatLng1);
builder.include(LatLng2);
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 17));
```

Any suggestion please?
Thanks

Comment: Calculate average of your two locations and animate your camera to that location.

Comment: is your code not shown whole path area ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies... I have solved it by adding every point in the route to the `LAtLngBounds.Builer` object and then moving the `camera`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was simple

This might help someone in the future if looking for this sort of feature.

This method is called after the `google direction API` returns the route from `location A to B`. `directionPoints` is the `list` of Points in the route.

```
public void handleResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints)
    {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++)
        {
            rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
        }

        //this polyline is stored so that it can be removed by calling drawnRoutePath.remove() if needed
        drawnRoutePath = googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
        prepareBuilder(directionPoints);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 17));
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The json response from the Google Direction API

```
"routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 27.7136953,
               "lng" : 85.32216629999999
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 27.7103725,
               "lng" : 85.3214952
            }
         },
.... etc
```

So I used this bound's `lat` and `lng` as parameter to `LatLngBounds.Builder`.

```
JSONObject jsonBound = ((JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONObject("bounds");
JSONObject jsonSouthWest = jsonBound.getJSONObject("southwest");
JSONObject jsonNorthEast = jsonBound.getJSONObject("northeast");
LatLng boundSouthWest = new LatLng(jsonSouthWest.getDouble("lat"),jsonSouthWest.getDouble("lng"));
LatLng boundNorthEast = new LatLng(jsonNorthEast.getDouble("lat"),jsonNorthEast.getDouble("lng"));
ArrayList<LatLng> bounds = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
bounds.add(boundNorthEast);
bounds.add(boundSouthWest);
```

and included these points in `LatLngBounds.Builder`

Comment: How do you get directionPoints

Answer (score 12):

I know you already find the answer, but here is my method to solve the problem

```
boolean hasPoints = false;
        Double maxLat = null, minLat = null, minLon = null, maxLon = null;

        if (polyline != null && polyline.getPoints() != null) {
            List<LatLng> pts = polyline.getPoints();
            for (LatLng coordinate : pts) {
                // Find out the maximum and minimum latitudes & longitudes
                // Latitude
                maxLat = maxLat != null ? Math.max(coordinate.latitude, maxLat) : coordinate.latitude;
                minLat = minLat != null ? Math.min(coordinate.latitude, minLat) : coordinate.latitude;

                // Longitude
                maxLon = maxLon != null ? Math.max(coordinate.longitude, maxLon) : coordinate.longitude;
                minLon = minLon != null ? Math.min(coordinate.longitude, minLon) : coordinate.longitude;

                hasPoints = true;
            }
        }

        if (hasPoints) {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(new LatLng(maxLat, maxLon));
            builder.include(new LatLng(minLat, minLon));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 48));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simplest way

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
  // Create a LatLngBounds that includes Australia.
  private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(
  new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));

// Set the camera to the greatest possible zoom level that includes the
// bounds 
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 0));
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views